# How to find out the password and user name of a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, joomla

In my mysql server i have a database named "joomla". But `http://localhost/joomla` gives "Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error". I want to check that whether i provide the correct user name and password in configuration.php file. For this i need to find out which user have permissions on joomla database. So how can i find out that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Login to the mysql server using an account that has adequate permissions and use `show grants for <name>` to get list of permitted DBs.

You won't be able to find the MySQL passwords this way though.

Comment: ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'sumitr' on host '%' getting this as an error (sumitr=username in configuration .php)